# Processing Arduino doesn't Start with Arduino Libary being used on Windows 7

Tags: arduino, processing

I have a problem of getting my Processing app to start when I'm using the Arduino library to work on it. I'm thinking just installing Linux on a partition of my hard drive to get it to work. I see the library text load but then it freezes up. I'm also using an anti virus called kaspersky. Here's my source code for the processing

```
import processing.serial.*;
import cc.arduino.*;

Arduino arduino= new Arduino(this, Arduino.list()[0], 57600);
int ledPin = 13;
boolean greenFlash = false;
boolean blueFlash = false;
boolean redFlash = false;
void setup()
{
size(600,600);
//println(Arduino.list());
//arduino = new Arduino(this, Arduino.list()[0], 57600);
arduino.pinMode(ledPin, Arduino.OUTPUT);
arduino.digitalWrite(ledPin, Arduino.HIGH);
}

void draw()
{
if(redFlash){
arduino.digitalWrite(12, Arduino.HIGH);
}
delay(mouseY);
arduino.digitalWrite(12, Arduino.LOW);
delay(mouseX);

if(greenFlash){
arduino.digitalWrite(11, Arduino.HIGH);
}
delay(mouseY);
arduino.digitalWrite(11, Arduino.LOW);
delay(mouseX);

if(blueFlash){
arduino.digitalWrite(10, Arduino.HIGH);
}
delay(mouseY);
arduino.digitalWrite(10, Arduino.LOW);
delay(mouseX);




}

void keyPressed(){
//flash = true;
if (key == 'R' || key == 'r'){
redFlash=true;
}
if (key == 'B' || key == 'b'){
blueFlash=true;
}
if (key == 'G' || key == 'g'){
 greenFlash=true;
}

}

void keyReleased(){
//flash = false;  

if (key == 'R' || key == 'r'){
 redFlash=false;
}
if (key == 'B' || key == 'b'){
 blueFlash=false;
}
if (key == 'G' || key == 'g'){
 greenFlash=false;
}
}
```

The arduino is loaded up with the standard firmata example to allow this to run. This has worked on mac so I'm sure it's a windows bug. I've looked though some forums and haven't found anything. If anyone can help that would be awesome.

EDIT:
it is the processing app that is freezing up. it starts but then the window dose not pop up. sometimes i have to go into task manager to kill it. also the processing compiler is 1.5.1

```
Display 0 does not exist, using the default display instead.
WARNING:  RXTX Version mismatch
Jar version = RXTX-2.2pre1
native lib Version = RXTX-2.2pre2
```

after this message it freezes up and dose nothing. iv wait about 5 minutes nothing happens.

Comment: Can you please provide some more detail? What compiler are you using? Is it your Arduino that freezes?

Answer (score 0):

Do some diagnostics: **simplify**

1. Are you able to run other basic Processing sketches (non-Arduino/non-Serial com)? (Java issue)
2. Are you able to connect and upload sketches to the Arduinio using the Arduino IDE? (COM issue)

If there answer to either of those is no, then you have a place to start looking.

I have read on the Arduino site that installed drivers for Windows 7 is a bit complicated. If you can't connect to the Arduinio using the IDE, then work that out first.

Comment: OK thanks. I completely forgot about the drivers. Big fail on my part thank you.